# Create function return type from input array

Tags: typescript

I wrote a function like this one

```js
// window.location.search = "?id1=123&id2=ABC&id3=456"

const { id1, id2, id3 } = readArgsFromURL("id1", {name: "id2", required: false}, {name: "id3", required: true})

console.log(id1) // 123
console.log(id2) // ABC
console.log(id3) // 456
```

I would like to provide typings for `readArgsFromURL` in such a way that VSCode autocompletes id1, id2 and id3 according to what the user specifies in the function arguments. Given that those are query params, they can be any string or a narrowed set of allowed string (just to avoid typos).

An example of what I would like VSCode to behave is

```js
// id3 should error as not specified as input
const { id1, id2, id3 } = readArgsFromURL("id1", {name: "id2", required: true})
```

Please note that `required` option is just used to throw error if the URL does not contain such query parameter, no influence on autocomplete feature

Here are the function and the typings I currently have:

```js
type KnownParam = 'id1' | 'id2' | 'id3'
type MyParamWithOptions = { name: KnownParam; required: boolean }
type MyParam = KnownParam | MyParamWithOptions

type MyParamParsed = { myName: KnownParam; value: string | null }
type MyParamResult = { [key in KnownParam]: string | null }

export const readArgsFromURL = (...myParams: MyParam[]): MyParamResult => {
    const withOpts = normalizeWithOptions(myParams)
    return readArgsFromURLWithOpts(withOpts)
}

const readArgsFromURLWithOpts= (
    myParams: MyParamWithOptions[],
): MyParamResult => {
    const urlParamsRaw = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    const urlParams = toLowerCaseParamNames(urlParamsRaw)
    const decoded: MyParamParsed[] = myParams.map(
        ({ name: myName, required }) => {
            const paramValue = urlParams.get(myName.toLowerCase())
            const validParamValue = paramValue != null && paramValue !== ''
            if (required && !validParamValue) {
                throw new Error(`Parameter '${myName}' not found`)
            }
            return !validParamValue
                ? { myName, value: null }
                : { myName, value: paramValue }
        },
    )
    return decoded.reduce((prev: MyParamResult, { myName, value }) => {
        prev[myName] = value
        return prev
    }, {} as MyParamResult)
}

function normalizeWithOptions(myParams: MyParam[]) {
    return [...myParams].map(mp =>
        typeof mp === 'string'
            ? ({ name: mp, required: true } as MyParamWithOptions)
            : (mp as MyParamWithOptions),
    )
}

function toLowerCaseParamNames(params: URLSearchParams) {
    const newParams = new URLSearchParams()
    for (const [name, value] of params) {
        newParams.append(name.toLowerCase(), value)
    }
    return newParams
}
```

Currently the behavior is the following

```js
// id3 is allowed
const { id1, id2, id3 } = readArgsFromURL("id1", {name: "id2", required: true})
```

I guess I should use a Mapped Type in combination with Pick, but I am unsure how to approach the solution to this problem.

Comment: but the search params are defined in runtime. It's not possible to get the values in compile time

Comment: I would like the user to specify what to pick from search params. If param `id1` is marked as `required` and it is not found in the query string, then an error will be thrown. If it is not marked as requried, then null is returned for `id1`. Those are all runtime checks. But the goal is to have `id1` autocompleted, not to ensure it actually exists in the URL.

Comment: so you just want to keys to exist, not to have the right values, right?

Comment: @wonderflame exactly

Comment: I do not think what you want to do is even possible... or I do not understand what you are asking for exactly.

Comment: The answer `This is not possible because...` is among the acceptable ones :)

Comment: Is this not it? https://tsplay.dev/m0vvnw

Comment: I guess it is close to the goal. When I remove id3, then id3 is accepted as returned field (fail). When I remove both id2 and id3, then id2 and id3 are NOT accepted (success). I am also playing with it to see if I can move forward from your solution. Thanks for the valuable contribution!

Comment: I think this can be a solution, based on @kelsny proposal! https://tsplay.dev/mpQK7W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those reaching here from a search engine, below's the full TypeScript solution without the implementation details.
If we remove some of the inputs, TS will complain about the missing fields.

```
type KnownName = "id1" | "id2" | "id3"
type MyParamWithOptions = { name: KnownName; required: boolean };
type MyParam = KnownName | MyParamWithOptions;

type AllowedResultField<K extends MyParam> = K extends MyParamWithOptions ? Extract<KnownName, K["name"]> : Extract<KnownName, K>
type IsRequiredField<T extends MyParam> = T extends MyParamWithOptions ? T["required"] : true
type FieldValue<T extends MyParam> = IsRequiredField<T> extends true ? (string) : (string | null)

declare function readArgsFromURL<T extends MyParam[]>(
  ...myParams: T
): {
  [K in T[number] as AllowedResultField<K>]: FieldValue<K>
    
};

const { id1, id2, id3 } = readArgsFromURL(
  "id1",
  { name: "id2", required: false },
  { name: "id3", required: true }
);
```